# How to create editable SDL2 text input boxes?

Tags: sdl2, c

[image]

Hi all, I'm working on an SDL2 project and I require multiple editable square textboxes as shown in the image above. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I have tried to look at text input documentation for SDL but it is nonexistent , the only thing I managed to find was a widget toolkit called Kiss ,  however If I have no clue how to install it as the instructions are so incredibly vague

Comment: I would recommend you to check out a GUI library called ImGui. It's a very powerful library with an easy installation, with a backend that is prepared to be used together with SDL.

Comment: @Daniel_1985 I'm using c not c++

Comment: There seems to be [c bindings](https://github.com/cimgui/cimgui) for ImGui...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to my answer: **rendering a dynamic text box onto the screen**, and **changing the text box based on user input**, which hopefully covers both parts of your question. I'm writing this based on the assumption that you're using standard SDL2 libraries and documentation, which (I hope?) are C/C++ blind.

### Dynamic text box: What you'll need

In SDL2, the usual way to draw a dynamic text box is that you will need the following things:

- an [SDL_Renderer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Renderer) to render the text box,
- a [TTF_Font](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf_49.html) font object,
- an [SDL_Surface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface),
- and a final [SDL_Texture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Texture) that is what will actually be drawn on the screen.

You will also need to include the **SDL_ttf** library, which is a font rendering library for text that is used within the SDL library. It might have been included in your installation - if not, [here is a link to get it.](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/)

### Dynamic text box: The implementation

First you can use the built-in SDL_ttf function [TTF_RenderText_BlendedWrapped](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/docs/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf_44.html) to render your given text string (which must first be converted into a char array) into an SDL_Surface. The maxLength parameter is the maximum allowable length of the text string before it wraps around into a second line, which is useful for dynamic text wrapping in your boxes to save time and headaches.

```
Surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(font, CharArray, color, maxLength);
```

Next you can use [SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface) to convert that surface into a texture, using your SDL_Renderer as the first parameter:

```
Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Surface);
```

And finally, you can draw that text box onto the screen using any other function you would use to draw a texture on screen.

The full text box constructor function that I use in my own SDL2 game, for your convenience:

```
/*
* Constructor with text, font, font color, and renderer.
* 
* @param t: The text in the text box.
* @param font: The font we are using.
* @param color: The color of the text.
* @param renderer: The renderer.
* @param maxLength: The maximum width of the text box before it wraps around.
*/
TextBox(string t, TTF_Font* font, SDL_Color color, SDL_Renderer* renderer, int maxLength)
{
    char CharArray[2000]; // Create a char array
    strcpy_s(CharArray, t.c_str()); // Convert the string into a char array for the surface function.

    Surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(font, CharArray, color, maxLength); // Make into a surface.
    Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Surface); // Turn the surface into a texture.
    TTF_SizeText(font, CharArray, &w, &h); // Size the texture so it renders the text correctly.
}
```

### Changing the text box for user input

To do this, you'll need to re-render the text box each time its text changes, since the text is rendered into an SDL_Surface as part of the rendering function. You'll need to overwrite the text box with a new one and re-render it each time the text is updated:

```
Box = TextBox(NewText, Font, TextColor, renderer, maxLength); // Re-render with the new text.
```

Comment: Thanks , however - I'm using C , not C++ - So most of your Textbox class has no direct equivelent For me in C ,  i.e. I am unable to use - strcpy_s(CharArray, t.c_str()); , and of course , scince im using C  I do not have classes , and can not instantiate

Comment: @BilalAhmed Yikes, I was hoping at least some of this would carry over to C. Not sure what I can do for you then, you've picked a tough battle.

Comment: so its impossible then?

Comment: @BilalAhmed You may be able to look into Vaillancourt's suggestion of using the C bindings for imGui, but beyond that I don't know if this is a thing that can be done. I hope you're able to find something though - I'm not an expert by any means.

Comment: I fanally managed to port It to C! - your advice has been invaluable to me!

Comment: @BilalAhmed Awesome!!! Glad I could help!

Comment: I know the textbox allready has wrapping , but is there a way i could get it to change line - when , say - the enter key is pressed?

Comment: @BilalAhmed Absolutely, you can have a press of the "Enter" key insert a newline character ("\n") into the text, which will (ideally, if you've set everything up correctly) move the text down to the next line.